# How do I spawn wolves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I spawn wolves in singleplayer Minecraft using [Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-110-single-player-commands-v311-official-download/); what command do I use?

Comment: Please improve your question. It's not even a question. It's a demand. I'm not sure many people respond well to demands.

Comment: Well... he *did* say please :P

Answer (score 11):

The command to spawn mobs using the SPC mod is `/spawn [name] [quantity]`. For example, you would type `/spawn wolf 5` to spawn five wolves.

Comment: Random question but - how do you access the console in single player?

Comment: It's a [mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=100267). You access it by hitting `T`, like talking in SMP.

Comment: @Raven you could make that a [true question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so it doesn't get asked so often in a comment tail...

Comment: in single player commands the commands do not require a slash, but even with the slash it would still work

Answer (score 3):

You can summon wolves using the following command:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~ ~
```

If you want to summon a tamed wolf, use the following syntax:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {Owner:<PlayerName>}
```

Note that you *cannot* use `@p` here, it must be the player's name typed out.

If you want to summon a wolf with a specific collar colour, use the command:

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~ ~ {CollarColor:14}
```

for example. Modify the number from 0 to 16 to change the colour.