# How do you open / enable the console in Single Player mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will I be able to make this work in vanilla Minecraft, or do I need a mod to enable it?

What features (if any) do I gain by accessing the console?

Thanks to Tobias for the suggestion, from [this thread.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/how-do-i-spawn-wolves)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "console" isn't a part of Vanilla Minecraft, it's part of the [Single Player Commands mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=100267). By installing the mod, you can type in commands (listed in the thread linked) by hitting <kbd>T</kbd>, as if you were chatting in SMP.

Here's a video from the developer showcasing the commands.

Comment: Any interest in updating this, now that vanilla has commands/cheats?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Done, see new answer.

Comment: @Richard That doesn't help fix the top accepted answer, though, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 9):

As single player now has commands as well<sup>1</sup> (albeit most depend on the "cheats" option on world creation): press the <kbd>/</kbd> (slash) key (or whatever key you have mapped to the "command" option in key mappings).

---

<sup>1</sup> Since [V1.3.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#1.3.1).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, and a lot has changed in Minecraft since this question was asked. In versions of Minecraft before 1.3, there were no single player commands, so in order to access such features, you needed to install external mods such as the Single Player Commands mod.

Now, you can access all these commands in-game without the need of installation of external mods. This can be done be typing `/` then your command, or typing `t` to open up your chat, then typing `/` and then your command. Also, in 1.4, command blocks were introduced, so you could have command blocks execute commands for you instead of the players having to do it themselves.

Command blocks could not be obtained from the creative menu, but rather by the command `/give @p 137` or if you're in 1.8 or later `/give @p command_block`. The command block console can be accessed by walking up to it and simple right-clicking it. Commands in command blocks do not need the `/` before the command to be executed. Command blocks can produce a redstone signal if the command they are executing returns as `true`, or they can execute a command when a redstone signal is received, (eg. teleporting a player to a house upon stepping on a pressure plate on a command block that has a `tp @p` command.)

I hope this helps explain all the new (or not so new) features of command blocks!

Comment: **"Now, you can access all these commands in-game without the need of installation of external mods."** Not necessarily. Some commands from SPC are missing.

Comment: @FinnRayment Really? Like which ones? I'm not aware of the features the SPC mod had, because I never used it.

Comment: **/gamemode** used a, c and s for gamemodes instead of numbers. There was a /fly command, /spawn, /alias, /ascend, /biome, and many more. Sure, some would of had name changes, but ALOT didn't make it. Compare the following links, to see what commands **do** and **don't** exist anymore, too many to type here.

Comment: **SPC:** http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Mods/Single_Player_Commands#Command_List  
**Minecraft:** http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands?cookieSetup=true#List_of_commands

Answer (score 1):

To enter a command, you type a <kbd>/</kbd> and then the command, inside the chat. To open the chat, press <kbd>t</kbd>(by default). The command `help`(so you enter `/help` in chat) gives you a list of commands, or alternatively you can browse [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) list.

But to enter a command, you must have priveleges to enter a command. You can get those priveleges by allowing them on world creation(`More World Options -> Allow Cheats: ON`), or if you have already created the world: `pause menu -> Open to LAN -> Allow Cheats: ON -> Start LAN world`. However, this opens your server to the LAN and needs to be done every session. You can disable this again by reloading the world.

Answer (score -1):

With the update, just toggle `allow cheats` and you're good.